# Qt - Stylesheet for disabled QPushButton under Windows 7 Basic Theme

Tags: qt4, qt4.7, qt4.8, qtstylesheets, qpushbutton

I can change the *font and font-color* of a **QPushButton** using the **StyleSheets**.
The Problem is that under the ***old Windows Theme the disabled Buttons shows a shaded font***, but i dont know how to get rid of this shaded front through StyleSheets. Can anyone please suggest your ideas about it. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Style for the normal state button:

```
QPushButton
{
     color: red;
}
```

Style for the "Disabled" state button:

```
QPushButton:!enabled
{
     color:blue;
}
```

This might fix your problem